# Fedora 20, tried akmod, kmod, nvidia proprietry installer still can not install on msi ge60/gtx660m

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, fedora, nvidia-graphics-card

I have fedora20, tried to install bumblebee,primus,nvidia 304xx drivers to my fedora installation. I tried akmod it froze at the prefdm process as i know it correct. Fedora logo comes up and it goes back saying installing and compiling the akmod. So i get into init3 and try to startx with the user. No screens found. SO i try kmod still similar error. I tried nvidia proprietry executable. Similar headaches. Primus also complains about "no configuration file found" and Cannot access secondary GPU - error: Could not load GPU driver even with nouveua drivers.

Please help me. It wasn't this buggy in older fedora versions.